# Mathjax : exponent too close from term

Tags: mathjax

I don't know how to fix the following issue : when I insert MathJax in a page with different equations, the exponent is too close from the variable or the term which has this component.

It is clear to me that the exponent "j" is too close from parenthesis and various terms: it is difficult to distinguish it.

How can I circumvent this issue? Am I obliged to insert a latex "," character or more generally put a space between the exponent and the term?

### Update 1

As suggested by Peter Krautzberger, below a capture of equation given in my link above.

[image: "j" exponent issue]

You can see that "`j`" exponent touches the parenthesis for the first left terms.

Comment: The rendering looks fine to me. You might want to add some images to show what you see (and what you'd like to see).

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I have put, in **UPDATE 1**, a capture of equation that illustrates my issue with "j" exponent.

Comment: Are you seeing this on all browsers or only particular browsers? If so, which ones and what is the browser and OS version?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I have add on the link http://31.207.34.24/test_mathjax/ another line **where I use "i" index instead of "j" and vice versa.** the exponent "j" seems to be too close from parenthesis or different terms : as you can see, I have not this problem with "i" index which is less large than "j" index. Have you got the same rendering on Firefox 57.0 with MacOS 10.9.5 or on others browsers and OS ???

Comment: Thanks! I've filed an issue on our tracker.at https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1869. You could switch to the CommonHTML or SVG output to work around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the font metrics of the STIX fonts. The italic "j" extends to the left of its bounding box by .124em (which amounts to a pixel or two at usual sizes), while the MathJax TeX font's italic "j" only extends to the left by .012em (1/10 as much). So when the superscript "j" is placed next to the base "v" in the STIX fonts, the bottom of the "j" extends to the left of its bounding box by a few pixels, and bumps the "v". This is inherent in the metrics of the STIX fonts.

One solution would be to switch to using the MathJax TeX fonts.  If you control the configuration of the page you are using, you could configure MathJax to not use the STIX fonts.  Otherwise, if you don't have control over the configuration, you could install the MathJax fonts locally, so at least your own view of the situation would be better.

Comment: -@Davide Cervone Thanks for your answer . Unfortunately, this issue appears with a local MathJax installation : how to configure MathJax for not using the STIX fonts ? Regards

Comment: I didn't mean install MathJax locally, I meant install the MathJax TeX fonts as local fonts (rather than web fonts).  That is, go to the fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf directory and install the fonts you find there as system fonts on your system.

Comment: If you want to configure MathJax to not allow STIX fonts, then use `MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": {fonts: ["TeX"]}});`  See the [MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#using-in-line-configuration-options) for more details.